# rvm install fail, refusing to pull with rebase: your working tree is not up to date

Tags: rvm

I am attempting to reinstall rvm. I ran rvm implode and then rm -rf ~/.rvm just to make sure it was blown away. Then I did this:

Johnny-Goodmans-MacBook-Pro:.rvm johnnygoodman$ bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
M       patches/ruby/fix-irb-completion.diff
Successfully checked out branch ''
patches/ruby/fix-irb-completion.diff: needs update
refusing to pull with rebase: your working tree is not up-to-date

ERROR: Failed pull/rebase origin

How do I update patches/ruby/fix-irb-completion.diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bug is already fixed in RVM:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```